# How to fill a closed line plot in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, asynchronous

I want to turn the inside of a closed line graph/plot into filled.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5DzH.png)

````
    result = loadJson(jsonFile1)
    volume = result[2]
    flow = result[3]

    result2 = loadJson(jsonFile2)
    volume2 = result2[2]
    flow2 = result2[3]

    plt.axhline(y=0, color='k')

    plt.plot(volume, flow, alpha = 0.5, label = jsonFile1)
    plt.plot(volume2, flow2, alpha=0.5, label = jsonFile2)
    plt.xlabel("Volume")
    plt.ylabel("Flow")


    plt.title("Comparison between " + jsonFile1 + " and " + jsonFile2)
    plt.legend(loc='upper right')

    plt.show()```
````

Comment: `plt.fill_between(x, upper_bound, lower_bound)` maybe what you want.

Comment: To fill a curve that forms a polygon: `plt.fill(x,y)`